# Spark dataframe pivot without aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Am new to spark, currently am trying to do a pivot from rows to columns without aggregation like i need the data to be duplicated after the pivot.

i have the data like below

```
+----+----------+--------+
|abc |col       |position|
+----+----------+--------+
|1234|183500000X|0       |
|1234|0202211120|1       |
|1234|VA        |2       |
|1234|Y         |3       |
|1234|183500000X|0       |
|1234|21174     |1       |
|1234|NC        |2       |
|1234|N         |3       |
|1234|null      |0       |
|1234|null      |1       |
|1234|          |2       |
|1234|          |3       |
|1234|null      |0       |
|1234|null      |1       |
|1234|          |2       |
|1234|          |3       |
```

i would like to change it to below format

```
+----------+----------+----------+---+---+
|   abc    |         0|         1|  2|  3|
+----------+----------+----------+---+---+
|1234      |183500000X|0202211120| VA|  Y|
|1234      |183500000X|21174     | NC|  N|
+----------+----------+----------+---+---+
```

whenever i tried to use `df.groupBy($"abc").pivot("position").agg(first($"col"))` ... am getting only one record instead of all.

is there a way to get all the records without aggregation.

do i need to join with another dataframe to pull out the data.. kindly suggest me  on the same.

Comment: Updated answer. You need to do something as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
        ("A", "1", "0", 1),
        ("A", "2", "1", 1),
        ("A", "VA", "2", 1),
        ("A", "7", "3", 1),
        ("A", "11", "0", 2),
        ("A", "22", "1", 2),
        ("A", "VAVA", "2", 2),
        ("A", "77", "3", 2),
        ("B", "1", "0", 3),
        ("B", null, "1", 3)
      )).toDF("abc", "col", "position", "grouping")

val result = df.groupBy("abc", "grouping")
               .pivot("position")
               .agg(expr("first(col)"))
               .drop("grouping")

result.show()

+---+---+----+----+----+
|abc|  0|   1|   2|   3|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|  A|  1|   2|  VA|   7|
|  A| 11|  22|VAVA|  77|
|  B|  1|null|null|null|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

Leaving the nulls aspect out, you need to do the following by adding a grouping number in some way to your data. That is the clue. That's a data wrangling exercise. I do not know your data well enough to proffer advice.

**Supporting Notes**

The issue is that the grouping looks to be sequential and we do not know if there are always with sets of 4 or N. How do we apply such a grouping? You  normally need a proper set of grouping keys, but we do not appear to have that here. Spark is less good at this type of thing and we need to preserve position, even with zipWithIndex this is a hard task.

The issue is more this than the .pivot in fact.

Comment: hi, Thanks for the answer. i think it wont suffice my answer as this group will give only one record per company...however from my question i should be able to get duplicates as well.

Comment: It's a guideline not the actual answer.

Comment: OK will do but I seem to remember an issue here

Comment: Thanks for the logic , i tried to add a column with "withColumn" provided as groupColumn for group by...kindly let me know whats the issue here

Comment: its quite hard to group unless sets of 4